# How to deal with Seg2Cat no results in channel query

Tags: categories, segments

I'm using [Low Seg2Cat](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/low-seg2cat) to retrieve the third segment of my url and pass it as category to filter a listing page. Problem is that when third segment is empty I have no-results, where I was expecting a full list.

Here my code:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" category="{segment_3_category_id}"}
```

URL : my_template/my_category [wohoo, get right result!]
URL : my_template/ [uh oh, no results at all :'/ ]

Normally in a situation with an empty category i.e. `category=""` it returns all results, so it is like Seg2Cat is passing some kind of string filtering category with one that doesn't exists.

For instance, this code works just fine, it returns all posts:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" category=""}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default the Seg2Cat extension will only populate the `{segment_n_category_id}` vars if the corresponding segment is present. So in your case when segment 3 is blank the `{segment_3_category_id}` var does not exist so it's passed to the channel entries tag as a raw string.

To fix this you can tweak the extension settings and set "Set all segments" as Yes. This will ensure that an empty var will be set if no match is found and the channel entries tag should behave as intended.

Comment: Just to clarify Dom's answer when segment_3 is blank EE treat the tag as a string, so will try and find category "{segment_3_category_id}" rather than "".

Comment: great explanation, now works as intended.

Comment: If you do set that setting (set all segments) and you do want that nothing shows up (e.g. invalid categories) you can prepend a zero to the parameter. e.g. `categories="0|{segment_3_category_id}"`